# prove that the following sequences are bounded from above

Tags: calculus

> let $a_n = \frac{1}{3^1+1} + \frac{1}{3^2+1} + ... + \frac{1}{3^n+1}$
>
> $b_n = \frac12 + \frac1{2 * 4} + ... + \frac1{2*4*...(2n)}$

its easy to show the 2 sequences are monotone rising, but how do i prove that they are bounded from above?

i couldent find another sequence that can be shown to always be larger and is bounded
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $3^k < 3^{k} + 1$ for all $k$, and so

$$\frac{1}{3^k + 1} < \frac 1 {3^k}$$

Therefore,

$$a_n = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{3^k + 1} < \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{3^k} \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {3^k} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} - 1 = \frac 1 2$$

This uses some facts about geometric series; if you haven't proven these, then try to. Alternatively, as Harald pointed out, there is a rather nice closed form for a *finite* geometric series.

---

Likewise, a rather poor upper bound for $b_n$ can be achieved by using the estimate

$$2^k < 2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2k)$$

Comment: One small error, one simplification: Your formula for the infinite sum is correct if the starting index is $0$, but here it is $1$. And you don't *need* the infinite sum. Just use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.